# wordpress logged in user in storyboard

Tags: php, wordpress, storyboard

trying to get logged in user in wordpress from within lightbox plugin:

`[iframe_loader type='lightbox' href='https://www.website.org/wp-content/uploads/articulate_uploads/TestCert/' size_opt='lightebox_default']`

this is a storyboard test that send results to a php page - code in php page is:

```
<?php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
/**
 * @example Safe usage: $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
 * if ( !($current_user instanceof WP_User) )
 *     return;
 */
echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . '<br />';
echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '<br />';
echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . '<br />';
echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . '<br />';
echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . '<br />';
?>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: above is not working i get error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_currentuserinfo() in /home/miemss5/public_html/wp-content/uploads/articulate_uploads/TestCert/TestCert/story_content/wp_user.php on line 2`

Comment: here is ref: to WP function: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata

Comment: resolved issue - see original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP needed the `include_once` to point to `wp-blog-header.php` within WordPress for the function to run.

```
include_once ( "../public_html/wp-blog-header.php" );

global $current_user;

echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n";
echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . "\n";
echo 'User level: ' . $current_user->user_level . "\n";
echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . "\n";
echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . "\n";
echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . "\n";
echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . "\n";
```